# How to get elements from nested <html> document?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html><head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<style type="text/css"></style></head>
    <frameset border="false" frameborder="O" framespacing="0" rows="0,*" cols="*">
        <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="frame_rsafp" src="rsa_flash_cookie.html" noresize="true" scrolling="no">
        <frameset border="false" frameborder="O" framespacing="0" rows="*,30" cols="*">
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="login_page" noresize="true" scrolling="yes">
                           #document
                             <html>
                               <form name="frmLogin" action="entry" class="login" method="post" target="_top" autocomplete="off">
                                   <span class="passfield">
                                       <input type="text" name="LoginUserId" onkeypress="return fSubmit(event);" value="" class="ipassword">
                                   </span>
                               </form>
                             </html>                             
            <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" name="footer" src="footer.html" noresize="true" scrolling="no">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

For above html code I want to set value to text field "**LoginUserId**".
I tried 
`document.getElementsByName("LoginUserId")[0].value = "MyValue";`
but it returns the error **Cannot set property 'value' of undefined**.
I can only get elements upto "**login_page**" and count of child elements of "**login_page**" returns **0**.

```
var ele = document.getElementsByName("login_page")[0].childNodes;
alert(ele.length);
```

How can I get elements of this nested html document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByName("login_page")[0];
var ele    = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var loginBox = document.getElementById('login_page');
var values   = loginBox.getElementsByName("LoginUserId")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the iframe first:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

and then you can work on that document

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to change the value of the `LoginUserId` input you can do this:

```
var inputField = document.querySelector("input[name=LoginUserId]");
inputField.value="test";
```